# Can cartodb be used with Drupal?

Tags: carto, drupal

I've found there's integration of DKAN into cartodb http://www.nucivic.com/publish-beautiful-maps-cartodb-dkan/ but does it really allow to setup a separate webpage with a cartodb map?